# Problem in using a second call to send() in C

Tags: c, windows, tcp, client-server, send

Right now I'm working in a simple Server that receives from client a code referring to a certain operation. The server receives this data and send back the signal that it's waiting for the proper data.

```
                   /*Server Side*/
                    if (codigoOperacao == 0)
                    {
                        printf("A escolha foi 0\n");
                        int bytesSent = SOCKET_ERROR;
                        char sendBuff[1080] = "0";
                        /*Here "send" returns an error msgm while trying to send back the signal*/
                        bytesSent = send(socketEscuta, sendBuff, 1080, 0);
                        if (bytesSent == SOCKET_ERROR)
                        {
                            printf("Erro ao enviar");
                            return 0;
                        }
                        else
                        {
                        printf("Bytes enviados : %d\n", bytesSent);
                        char structDesmontada[1080] = "";
                        bytesRecv = recebeMensagem(socketEscuta, structDesmontada);
                        printf("structDesmontada : %s", structDesmontada);
                        }
                    }
```

Following here is the client code responsible for sending the operation code and receiving the signal

```
                char sendMsg[1080] = "0";
            char recvMsg[1080] = "";
            bytesSent = send(socketCliente, sendMsg, sizeof(sendMsg), 0);
            printf("Enviei o codigo (%d)\n", bytesSent);
            /*Here the program blocks in a infinite loop since the server never send anything*/
            while (bytesRecv == SOCKET_ERROR)
            {
            bytesRecv = recv(socketCliente, recvMsg, 1080, 0);
            if (bytesRecv > 0)
            {
                printf("Recebeu\n");
            }
```

Why this is happening only in the second attempt to send some data? Because the first call to send() works fine.
Hope someone can help!!
Thnks

Comment: been years since i've worked with c sockets, but have you tried using the NON_BLOCK flag? on a side note, what kind of sockets are you using?

Comment: And what is the error message?

Comment: SOCKET_ERROR. I'm using TCP connection. I don't think that the NON_BLOCK will solve the problem since i'm having trouble with the send() and it's not blocking :P. But thanks.
EDIT: As i thought, NON_BLOCK didn't worked *sigh*

Comment: There should be a more descriptive error, though I'm not familiar with windows specifically; you'd use errno on BSD to get it.  Your code looks fine at a glance, though you are sending uninitialized bytes.

Comment: Is the client receiving the first "message"?

Comment: Yep, the client is receiving the first message. The problem occurs with the second call to send(), which returns -1. EDIT: I manage to obtain the Error Code, it's 10038!

Comment: By some reason, the first socket gets "deleted". I solved the problem by making a copy of the socket at the very beggining. Why this happens?

Comment: @Paulo have you checked with netstats that the socket is really getting close? if so, are you closing the socket on the other end?

Comment: Error code 10038: An operation was attempted on something that is not a socket. Either the socket handle parameter did not reference a valid socket, or for select, a member of an fd_set was not valid.

Comment: I checked that, and actually the socke was getting closed. I found out that the first recvBuff was to small for the incoming message, and it was overflowing and ocasionally overwriting the socket variable. Omg, I lost almost 4hours in this

Answer (score 0):

I sorted it out. The first receive buffer was to small for the incoming message and it got overflowed, erasing the SOCKET socketEscuta variable. Now it's working fine. Thanks for the tips!